# Example of apple server-to-server notification responseBodyV2DecodedPayload content (production)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have managed to setup my server to receive notifications from Apple Server Notification when for example a user asks for refund an in-app-purchase.

But there is no example at all of what the `responseBodyV2DecodedPayload` look like with real data.

Can someone share an example of the complete payload (decoded) so i can see all the fields that are inside please (for a `REFUND` `NotificationType` at least) ?

The apple documentation stops too soon and there are NO examples at all and no way to receive a "real" test notification payload.

Here is what i receive with a test notification :

```
{
  "notificationType":"TEST",
  "notificationUUID":"9e376dba-f5f8-40d0-a9d3-336a2c8ce092",
  "data : {"bundleId":"com.example.test","environment":"Sandbox"},
  "version":"2.0",
  "signedDate":1678118421479
}
```

I am pretty sure that the real notification has more fields especially in the [data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/jwstransaction).

But there is no documentation or example of the `keys` inside the `JWSTransaction` [object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/jwstransaction) that seems to be nested inside the `data`.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : Is it also possible to receive a full test payload from a "fake" production request ?

I have asked Apple support about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Smee](https://smee.io/) was crucial when I was doing sandbox testing.  Payloads can vary based on the transaction type.  Therefore it is best to set up a webhook like Smee that will forward the Sandbox payload to your local environment for extensive testing.

1. Add the Smee url as your `Sandbox Server URL` in your `App Information` within App Store Connect.
2. Follow the few simple steps on Smee to configure your local environment.

Voila! Your sandbox S2S notifications are sent to your local application.

** Remember to remove the url from your App's setting in App Store Connect when finished